# How to temporarily repair a hole in a window pane?

Tags: hole, glass, hole-repair

I came home yesterday and found a hole in one of my window glass panels. 
Looks like a rock hit it from the outside of the house, somehow.

I am going to have to replace the glass panel anyway in another 6 months or so. Meanwhile, I am looking to plug this hole for a little while (primarily so insects dont get in and my air con bills don't go through the roof). So it doesn't have to be pretty.

Would applying clear packaging tape on both sides of the hole, leaving a little gap on one side and filling it up with some sort of resin/epoxy do the trick ?

If so, what type of resin should I be after ? If not, how could I plug this hole ? 
The window gets plenty of sunlight

Another option I was thinking was to fill the hole with a clear sealant like http://www.selleys.com.au/sealants/co-polymer/all-clear/

All in all, how do i plug a hole in a glass panel ?

This is a picture (the 'ridges' and 'cracks' are on the inside):

[image]

Comment: How big is the glass pane, single or double and how thick?

Comment: @GaryBak Single Pane.About 851mm in width and 1046mm in height (the glass goes a few mm into the frame).. I think the thickness is about 4 mm

Comment: You should be able to find the rock (if that's what it was). Also look for bullet holes further in the house.  When you find the projectile, a private investigator may be able to link it to the perps.

Comment: @BrockAdams We actually didn't find the rock. It wasn't inside. Outside, there are plenty of rock about 8 feet from the window. Am only guessing it was a rock. Didn't find any bullet holes further in the house either (The window is in Australia - so gun availability is fairly low)further. Since we didn't find a projectile, we are not ruling out a bird doing the damage ? But could it be an air rifle ? What do you think ?

Comment: Air rifle pellets can be hard to find.  That could be it.  The rock *might* have bounced off (I've more experience shooting glass than chucking rocks at it).  If it was a bird, that impact should have killed it (but something *might* have removed the body).

Comment: @BrockAdams So in your experience does this seem like a bullet hole ?

Comment: I've seen bullet holes in glass that look remarkably similar, but haven't made a proper study of all the variables.  So, IMO, it could be, but I wouldn't swear to it in court.  PS: in the USA you can get security video systems starting at less than $100.

Comment: If you google images for bullet hole glass, you'll see mostly round holes with a spider web type fracture pattern.  I don't think it's from a bullet.   That's the good news!

Answer (score 9):

I'd do the packaging tape and call it a day. If the glass is clean it'll hold no problem. If you're really worried, silicone or similar would fill the void between the tape.

Then, start looking for your neighborhood vandal.

Answer (score 4):

Clamp the glass between two pieces of plywood, using a bolt and nut.

[image]